# Analytical Solution to a nonlinear system of equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, problem-solving, nonlinear-system, advice

Is it possible to analytically solve for x,y,z in the following system, and if so how would one go about it?

$a_{1} (y - 2x + z) - x + 2x^{3} - a_{2}x = 0$

$a_{1} (z - 2y + x) - y + 2y^{3} - a_{2}y = 0$

$a_{1} (x - 2z + y) - z + 2z^{3} - a_{2}z = 0$

I've tried numerous methods such as cyclic permutations of the three equations and substitution but none seem to work, hence any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is a closed form solution for any cubic (it's ugly, but it exists), so it seems like you could solve for on variable and then "plug and chug" as it were. The formula actually simplifies when you have no squared term, which you don't

Answer (score 2):

Let $\,s = x+y+z\,$ then the first equation can be written as:

$$
\begin{align}
0 &= a_{1} (y - 2x + z) - x + 2x^{3} - a_{2}x
\\ &= a_{1} (s - 3x) - x + 2x^{3} - a_{2}x
\\ &= 2x^{3} - (3 a_1 + a_2 + 1) x + a_{1} s
\end{align}
$$

The same equation is satisfied by $\,y\,$ and $\,z\,$. Assuming $\,x,y,z\,$ are distinct, they are the roots of the same depressed cubic, so their sum must be $\,s = 0\,$, and the equations reduce to:

$$
2t^{3} - (3 a_1 + a_2 + 1) t = 0 \quad\quad \Big|\quad t = x, y, z
$$

Therefore the non-trivial distinct solutions of the system are permutations of:

$$
x = \sqrt{\frac{3a_1+a_2+1}{2}} \;,\quad y = - \sqrt{\frac{3a_1+a_2+1}{2}}\;, \quad z = 0
$$

This leaves the case where pairs of $\,x,y,z\,$ are equal to be solved separately.

---

[ *EDIT* ] The following covers the remaining case where two solutions are equal. Assume WLOG that $\,y=z\,$, then the last equation becomes redundant, and the system reduces to:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
2x^{3} - (a_2+1) x - 2a_{1} (x-y) &= 0
\\ 2y^{3} - (a_2 + 1)y + a_{1} (x-y) &= 0
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

It can be seen "*by inspection*" that a solution is $\,x=y\,$ where $\,x\,$ is a root of $\,2x^{3} - (a_2+1) x = 0\,$, which gives the identical triplets $\,x = y = z \in \left\{0, \pm \sqrt{\dfrac{a_2+1}{2}}\right\}\,$ as solutions.

To find all solutions, the first equation gives $\,y\,$ as a cubic in $\,x\,$, then substituting into the second equation gives an equation of degree $\,9\,$ in $\,x\,$ alone. We know from the previous step that $\,2x^{3} - (a_2+1) x\,$ must be a factor, so that leaves a sextic in $\,x\,$, which in the end turns out to be a cubic in $\,x^2\,$ (courtesy [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=resultant%282x%5E3+-+%282a+%2B+b+%2B+1%29+x+%2B+2a+y%2C+2y%5E3+-+%28a+%2B+b+%2B+1%29y+%2B+a+x%2C+y%29)):

$$
x^2 (a_2 - 2 x^2 + 1)^2 + 6 a_1 x^2 (a_2 - 2 x^2 + 1) - 2 a_1^2 (a_2 - 6 x^2 + 1) - 6 a_1^3 = 0
$$

Comment: I see, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Notice the symmetry in the equations.  Adding them all together, we find that
$$-(x+y+z)+2(x^3+y^3+z^3)-a_2(x+y+z) = 0$$
$$2(x^3+y^3+z^3) = (1+a_2)(x+y+z).$$
Now, we utilize the convenient factored form:
$$x^3+y^3+z^3 - (x+y+z) = (x+y+z)(x+y+z+1)(x+y+z-1),$$
to write the above equation as
$$(x+y+z)(x+y+z+1)(x+y+z-1) = \frac{a_2-1}{2}(x+y+z).$$
Assuming $x+y+z \ne 0$,
$$(x+y+z+1)(x+y+z-1) = \frac{a_2-1}{2}.$$
Thus,
$$z = \pm \sqrt{\frac{a_2+1}{2}}-x-y.$$
Notice that if we substitute this into the original first equation, we find
$$a_1(\sqrt{\frac{a_2+1}{2}}-3x)+2x^3-a_2x = 0.$$
This is a cubic in $x$, which you can solve.
Proceed in a similar fashion in the second original equation to find a cubic in terms only of $y$.  Finally, solve $z = \pm \sqrt{\frac{a_2+1}{2}}-x-y$ to find $z$.

Note, you will also have to check for solution when $x+y+z = 0$, but I think this will at least give you a good start.

By using $s = x+y+z$ and looking at first part of dxiv's answer, this case is very simple.

Comment: Noted, thank you very much